# threejs cannot be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

Hi I am trying to build the "get started" application from the threejs website.  https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene

I made a html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <title>BIM Demo</title>
    <script>"/js/three.min.js"</script>
    <script  type="module" src="./js/view.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>BIM DEMO</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I specified my view.js as a module since I want to be able to use the import statement to import my typescript files, but when I try to show my application in the browser I get the message THREE not found.
I tried adding it with yarn but it does not work.

This is my structure

[image: my structure]

Comment: `<script>"/js/three.min.js"</script>` should be `<script src="/js/three.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Use the non-minified version `three.js` for development -- especially if you are just learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `three.min.js` file is wrongly included. Your HTML should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <title>BIM Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/view.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>BIM DEMO</h1>
</body>
</html>
```